# Java(8): How to extract an specific class item from objects array?

Tags: java, java-8

I need to work on an Objects array which has the following value:

```
objectsArray = {Object[3]@10910} 
 {Class@10294} "class com.ApplicationConfiguration" -> {ApplicationConfiguration@10958} 
    key = {Class@10294} "class com.ApplicationConfiguration"
    value = {ApplicationConfiguration@10958} 
 {Class@10837} "class com.JoongaContextData" -> {JoongaContextData@10960} 
    key = {Class@10837} "class com.JoongaContextData"
    value = {JoongaContextData@10960} 
 {Class@10835} "class com.SecurityContext" -> {SecurityContext@10961} 
    key = {Class@10835} "class com.SecurityContext"
    value = {SecurityContext@10961}
```

The code which creates the objects array is:

```
public class ProcessDetails {
    private UUID myId;
    private Date startTime;
    private ResultDetails resultDetails;
    private long timeout;
    .
    .
    .
}

public interface ProcessStore extends Map<Class, Object> {
    <T> T unmarshalling(Class<T> var1);

    <T> void marshalling(T var1);

    ProcessDetails getProcessDetails();
}

Object[] objectsArray = processStore.entrySet().toArray();
```

I need to extract a value from the **ApplicationConfiguration** type item.

**Note that it is not always the first array item!**

For start, I tried to do the following:

```
    List<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfigurations = Arrays.stream(objectsArray)
            .filter(item -> item instanceof ApplicationConfiguration)
            .map(item -> (ApplicationConfiguration)item)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

in order to get a list with the specific item.
For some reason I got an empty list.

Why?

Comment: Can you add the defintion of the object array ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] with the objects your are using please. This would probably explain the resutl

Comment: Hi, this looks like a custom `toString()` method being used on a class-to-instance map. Could you please make the question a bit clearer by adding the `toString` implementation?

Comment: @Benoit added the code

Comment: It doesn't look like your array contains `ApplicationConfiguration` instances as direct elements.It contains instances of some other classes.

Comment: Your Objects[] array does not contain any instanceof `ApplicationConfiguration`. Therefore you become an empty list.

Comment: @Michal Your'e right... It contains maps... I'll check it...

Comment: Just a hint: you array contains something that has `key` and `value`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objectsArray` contains map entries, and you need to filter the values of those entries.

```
List<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfigurations = 
    Arrays.stream(objectsArray)
          .map(obj -> (Map.Entry<Class, Object>) obj)
          .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
          .filter(item -> item instanceof ApplicationConfiguration)
          .map(item -> (ApplicationConfiguration)item)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, it would be cleaner if you changed

```
 Object[] objectsArray = processStore.entrySet().toArray();
```

to

```
 Map.EntryMap.Entry<Class,Object>[] objectsArray = processStore.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
```

so that you can write:

```
List<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfigurations = 
    Arrays.stream(objectsArray)
          .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof ApplicationConfiguration)
          .map(e -> (ApplicationConfiguration) e.getValue())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there a way to get only the item instead of getting it inside a list? Thanks

Comment: @dushkin If you expect at most a single element to be returned, use `findFirst()` instead of `collect()`. It will return an `Optional<ApplicationConfiguration>`.

Comment: That `toArray` call still is an unchecked operation, as Java does not really support generic arrays. A cleaner solution would not to use an array at all, i.e. `List<Map.Entry<Class,Object>> list = new ArrayList<>(processStore.entrySet());` has the benefit of compile-time safety while even being sightly faster at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to find instances of `ApplicationConfiguration` directly, on an array of type `Map.Entry<K,V>[]` produced by [`Map#entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) and a subsequent call to [`Set#toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#toArray()).

Instead, try this:

```
List<ApplicationConfiguration> boxes = Arrays.stream(objectsArray)
            .map(entry -> ((Map.Entry<Class<?>, Object>) entry))
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(ApplicationConfiguration.class))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(v -> (ApplicationConfiguration) v)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `entry.getKey()` is a `Class`, so it will never be `instanceof ApplicationConfiguration`